# How to Update Apache to allow Pseudostreaming on CENTOS 5.5 & WHM

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I can't figure out how to get pseudostreaming on my Apache server (CENTOS 5.5 i686).

I've read [this article](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html) and [these install instructions](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2).

I cannot install `httpd-devel` or `mod_ssl` via yum; I get the error "package not found".  One person mentioned that they think WHM/CPanel breaks yum.

I have found some RPM packages:

> rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/13945478/dir/centos_5/com/mod_ssl-2.2.3-43.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm.html
>
> rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/13944425/dir/centos_5/com/httpd-devel-2.2.3-43.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm.html

But as I am not a unix admin, I am unsure of where to go from here.  Can someone point me in the right direction? (Please remember that I am very junior in linux administration.)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for not directly answering this one - I've got that module up and running with apache, but unfortunately on debian linux, so the packages are different, and perhaps you need to find correct packages for you as well (maybe download the files manually and then install them from files via "rpm -i *filename*").

Anyway, I wanted to point out maybe a more plug and play solution for apache ... check out [xmoovstream](http://stream.xmoov.com) - it's doing the same job, but runs on php so it should work with your apache as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can always submit a ticket to cPanel support for help.